# Mapbox zoom-in on mapDidLoad

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox to load a map, and it seems the map is zoom to the maximum. I want the map to look smaller. How do I zoom in on map load?

Here's the the code for loading the map. The code loads my current location and it looks so big. I want the map to be zoom in by default rather than having to click on the +- to zoom in and zoom out on the map. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Geolocation</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<a href='#' id='geolocate' class='ui-button'>Find me</a>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGltbGlzdGVuIiwiYSI6ImNqaWs5eWltbTAybG8za21zNjVuZjg5MW4ifQ.xCKtim61H1YXAkU5KT9-FQ';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets');

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

// This uses the HTML5 geolocation API, which is available on
// most mobile browsers and modern browsers, but not in Internet Explorer
//
// See this chart of compatibility for details:
// http://caniuse.com/#feat=geolocation
if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Geolocation is not available';
} else {
      map.locate();
}

// Once we've got a position, zoom and center the map
// on it, and add a single marker.
map.on('locationfound', function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.bounds);

    myLayer.setGeoJSON({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]
        },
        properties: {
            'title': 'Here I am!',
            'marker-color': '#ff8888',
            'marker-symbol': 'star'
        }
    });

    // And hide the geolocation button
    geolocate.parentNode.removeChild(geolocate);
});

// If the user chooses not to allow their location
// to be shared, display an error message.
map.on('locationerror', function() {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Position could not be found';
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't post your API token on a public form.

Comment: Maybe this question [**stackexchange - Setting max zoom in mapbox map?**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217678/setting-max-zoom-in-mapbox-map) might be of some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the zoom in  your function with

```
map.setZoom(5);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Geolocation</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<a href='#' id='geolocate' class='ui-button'>Find me</a>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGltbGlzdGVuIiwiYSI6ImNqaWs5eWltbTAybG8za21zNjVuZjg5MW4ifQ.xCKtim61H1YXAkU5KT9-FQ';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets');

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

// This uses the HTML5 geolocation API, which is available on
// most mobile browsers and modern browsers, but not in Internet Explorer
//
// See this chart of compatibility for details:
// http://caniuse.com/#feat=geolocation
if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Geolocation is not available';
} else {
      map.locate();
}

// Once we've got a position, zoom and center the map
// on it, and add a single marker.
map.on('locationfound', function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.bounds);

    myLayer.setGeoJSON({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]
        },
        properties: {
            'title': 'Here I am!',
            'marker-color': '#ff8888',
            'marker-symbol': 'star'
        }
    });

    map.setZoom(5);

    // And hide the geolocation button
    geolocate.parentNode.removeChild(geolocate);
});

// If the user chooses not to allow their location
// to be shared, display an error message.
map.on('locationerror', function() {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Position could not be found';
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe offer a working example [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mb7dsej9/)

Comment: Hi, I tried the code, but the map still looked the same. I tried to change the number for {zoom:5} to 10, 15, and 1, and it seems it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Oh I understand. I edited my answer. Try including map.setZoom in your function

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map.setView([latitude, longitude], zoom);`:

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGltbGlzdGVuIiwiYSI6ImNqaWs5eWltbTAybG8za21zNjVuZjg5MW4ifQ.xCKtim61H1YXAkU5KT9-FQ';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets');
map.setView([40.7290255, -74.0026558], 13);

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

// This uses the HTML5 geolocation API, which is available on
// most mobile browsers and modern browsers, but not in Internet Explorer
//
// See this chart of compatibility for details:
// http://caniuse.com/#feat=geolocation
if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Geolocation is not available';
} else {
      map.locate();
}

// Once we've got a position, zoom and center the map
// on it, and add a single marker.
map.on('locationfound', function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.bounds);

    myLayer.setGeoJSON({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]
        },
        properties: {
            'title': 'Here I am!',
            'marker-color': '#ff8888',
            'marker-symbol': 'star'
        }
    });

    // And hide the geolocation button
    geolocate.parentNode.removeChild(geolocate);
});

// If the user chooses not to allow their location
// to be shared, display an error message.
map.on('locationerror', function() {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Position could not be found';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Geolocation</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<a href='#' id='geolocate' class='ui-button'>Find me</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, how do I use the map.setView([40.7290255, -74.0026558], 13) to my current location?

Comment: @Julia, in your `locationfound` event handler you get `coordinates: [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]`. Just use them.

Comment: @Julia, happy to help.